# What is this breech mount with three flanges and a single linking pin?

Tags: lens, lens-mount, equipment-identification, vivitar, breech-mount

I bought this Vivitar lens cheap and I'm having trouble identifying the mount. I believe it's a Version 4 Serial number is 22128668

[image: Vivitar mount]

Comment: do you have its diameter?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is likely a **[Canon FL mount](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Canon_FL_lens_mount)**. If you are looking for an adapter, it is compatible with the [Canon FD mount](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Canon_FD_lens_mount) using stop-down metering. See [Evolution of the Canon FD Mount](https://oldlenses.blogspot.com/2013/01/evolution-of-canon-fd-mount.html).

If you'd like, you can measure the mount diameter to compare with a list of lens mounts ([alphabetical](http://www.graphics.cornell.edu/~westin/misc/mounts-alphabetical.html), [by-register](http://www.graphics.cornell.edu/~westin/misc/mounts-by-register.html), [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lens_mount)).

[image: FL and FD mounts]

Comment: There's no *may be* to it, the lens *is* an FL mount lens.